# Problems disabling search using jQuery Chosen

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I can't seem to get the option to disable the search functionality using the Chosen plugin working.

I've tried everything from this question without any luck: [jQuery Chosen plugin without search field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048289/jquery-chosen-plugin-without-search-field)

Sample code:

```
<select multiple=" " style="width:150px">
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
  <option value="c">c</option>
  <option value="aa">aa</option>
  <option value="bb">bb</option>
  <option value="cc">cc</option>
</select>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$( "select" ).addClass( "chosen-select" ).chosen( 
    { disable_search: true, 
      disable_search_threshold: 50 } 
);
```

I've tried all combinations of the above options and nothing seems to work.  In my example, if I typed the letter 'a' into the search box, I wouldn't expect to see filtered results.

Here's a link to the jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ycxb8wm4/3/

Comment: According to the source code for `chosen.js`, those settings are not actually checked in "multiple" mode, so have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code that hide dropdown div

```
$( "select" ).next().find( ".chosen-drop" ).hide();
```

Or use css

```
.chosen-container .chosen-drop{
  display:none;
}
```